# Worklight session memory replication

Tags: session, authentication, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to configure memory to memory replication in WebSphere Application Server for worklight application.

```
  The following are the steps i have done.
       1. Created cluster in WAS with two server enabling memery to memory replication.
       2. Deployed the worklight authentication application.
       3. In each server, i have enabled the replication mode to server and client.
       4. I have authenticated with one server. when i stopped the server it asking for logging in again.

  Can any one suggest me with the approach i need to follow to configure the memory to memory replication for worklight.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Memory-Memory replication does not work for IBM Worklight sessions.
IBM Worklight is stateful. It caches session state within the server memory. The result is that if one Worklight Server is taken offline, active user sessions are lost and the client is asked to log on again.

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/c_clustering.html